# Consume C++ boost.asio Rest API by C#

Tags: c#, c++, rest, boost

I have a rest API that is returning proper data, the problem is when i am consuming is from a C# code. Its returning bad gateway

following are my both codes for server

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
std::string make_daytime_string()
{
        using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
        time_t now = time(0);
        return ctime(&now);
}

int main()
{
        try
        {
                boost::asio::io_service io_service;

                tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1313));

                for (;;)
                {
                        cout << "listening for socket" << endl;
                        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
                        acceptor.accept(socket);


                        cout << "listening for socket" << endl;
                        std::string message = make_daytime_string();
                        message = "I am a response from rest service baby !!!";
                        boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
                        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
                }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
                std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

and for consuming it i have the following c# code

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.17.85:1313/");
req.Method = "GET";
WebResponse rep = req.GetResponse();
```

I dont seem to understand the problem, because it is easily consumed from the web browser but its returning 502 (Bad Gateway) from this code.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Such as fiddler for example?

Comment: There's no REST, there's no API. You simply have a socket server with a rudimentary text protocol.

Comment: Just use regular sockets from C#, there is no HTTP in your C++ code , it is plain sockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply writing into a socket, there is no HTTP in your response, browsers are "good" enough to detect this kind of problem. You need to format your code using HTTP protocol.

Please check the [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for HTTP 1.1 (I think this is the most common version).